# System is not able to find sphinxtrain binaries

Tags: windows-7, cmusphinx

I am creating an acoustic model on windows 7. I have downloaded the sphinxbase and sphinxtrain. Now when i try to execute 
"python ../sphinxtrain/scripts/sphinxtrain -t an4 setup"
command then it says that failed to find sphinxtrain binaries. I wanted to know that are these different for windows? But if they are same then why it is not finding them. I have also updated the path variable.

Answer (score 1):

You need to download package with binaries:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/cmusphinx/files/sphinxtrain/5prealpha/sphinxtrain-5prealpha-win32.zip/download

Or compile it before training. It is recommended to use prebuilt package.